# How to install driver of HL-5450DN in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I want to install the driver of HL-5450DN brother printer in Ubuntu 18.04. There are two driver files: `hl5450dncupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb` and `hl5450dnlpr-3.0.0-1.i386.deb`. It is no problem to install `hl5450dncupswrapper`. However, `hl5450dnlpr` can not be installed. I always get this error:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hl5450dnlpr.postinst: 3:     
/var/lib/dpkg/info/hl5450dnlpr.postinst:     
/opt/brother/Printers/HL5450DN/inf/braddprinter: not found
```

So, what shall I do next?

Comment: I wish I could upvote this question even more. I find myself googling to find this specific question whenever I want to install a Brother printer. Finding the [installer link](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5450dn_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625) (mentioned in the answer below) is nigh impossible through Brother's own website. It asks all sorts of irrelevant things first, like your location and printer model, and then presents the .deb files on their own, which aren't enough.

Answer (score 4):

The driver tool didn't work for me either, but here is how I solved it:

Printer HL1210w, ia32-libs is not available to install normally, `braddprinter` file is there but I can't execute it, `dpkg --force-all install` not working)

```
file braddprinter
```

you will see a dynamic library (`.so`),  use it in the next command (mine was `ld-linux.so.2`)

```
apt-file search ld-linux.so.2
```

this will show one ore more packet names. You are interested in ones that have `-i386` (mine `libc6`)

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```

this will give the libraries that you probably miss.
Now run the

```
dpkg install --force-all
```

Comment: Works! Thank you. I had to change : to - in the line "sudo apt-get install libc6:i386"

Answer (score 3):

perhaps you let the Brother Installer Tool see if it can sort things for you; if you go here http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadend.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hl5450dn_all&os=128&dlid=dlf006893_000&flang=4&type3=625 and click to download and **SAVE** what will be **linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz**

If you open a terminal; copy each command in line by line; paste each line into the terminal; (hit the ENTER key after each paste;) then on to the next command;

```
cd Downloads

gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1.gz

sudo bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.0-1 HL-5450DN
```

and see if that does any better

Comment: Perfect! It works very fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: THANK YOU.  My specific case was (first" "gunzip linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1.gz" then (second) "bash linux-brprinter-installer-2.2.1-1 DCPL2540DW"   .. Note, I skipped the "Will you specify the Device URI?" in the command line interactions, but then I (using the "Printers" UI component in ubuntu) .. just deleted the printer and re-added, but it found the driver this time.  Been working on this for 2 hours.  Thanks!!